# Print list-objects within sortedDictionary

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

So I'm trying to print out the members of my list. I'm using the following dictionary-structure: `SortedDictionary<string,List<int>>` where i'm using a string as the key.

In my function `ShowContents` I'm trying to print out what entry i'm looking at, and the amount of elements, as well as what the elements are. This is where i'm struggling. I'm just getting `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]`instead of the objects.

Here's my current code:

```
SortedDictionary<string,List<int>> jumpStats = new SortedDictionary<string,List<int>>(); // jumpstats[0] == (volt, 10m)
public string ShowContents()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item in jumpStats)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: has {1} entries with values {2}", item.Key, item.Value.Count(), item.Value));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        public SortedDictionary<string,List<int>> addjumpStats() //Adding information about the jump to the dictionary
        {
            try
            {
                jumpStats.Add("Volt", new List<int>());
                jumpStats["Volt"].Add(12);
                jumpStats["Volt"].Add(13);
                jumpStats["Volt"].Add(15);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Element already exists with the same key");
            }
            return jumpStats;
        }
```

Example output right now: `Volt: 3 System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]`

Comment: What are you expecting `item.Value` to print? Imagine instead of a `List<int>` you had a List<SomeComplexClass>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your append function you're outputting item.Value which is a `List<int>` hence why you are seeing the class name - the ToString function of a List does not know to concatenate all the values in the list together - it merely returns the class name.  You need to tell it what to do.  An easy way to do this is to use string.join:

```
string.Join(",", item.Value)
```

And in context:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item in jumpStats)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: has {1} entries with values {2}", item.Key, item.Value.Count(),  string.Join(",", item.Value));
}
return sb.ToString();
```